# PHP regex for allowing specific usernames

Tags: php, regex

This is my first question here. Currently I'm developing a PHP forum script and I want to let people register a username abiding by my rules.

**The rules are simple:**

- First character must be a letter
- They can also use numbers but it isn't the first
- They can use fullstop/underscore once but not at the end of a username

Please help me by putting down a function. I read some tutorial but don't understand regular expressions well. And for this reason I'm stuck. Thanks in advance for your answer.

Added after 20 min:

Thanks for answering, I have one more thing to ask, Can I detarmine dumb usernames?? E.G. aaa123, ab-cd,uuuu...Than How?

Comment: Is there a minimum length? Otherwise 'a' is valid.

Comment: Yes 4-12 char. are allowed. But I can detarmine the length. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: the rules seem arbitrary, what's there point? what harm would come to me using a user-name that does not comply?

Comment: @dragon, Nothing much, just want clean username..Also im not familiar with regex..It may help me to learn..Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the parts you describe:

> - First character must be a letter

It starts `^[A-Za-z]`

> - They can also use numbers but it isn't the first

`[A-Za-z0-9]*` in the middle

> - They can use fullstop/underscore once but not at the end of a username

Optionally, have an underscore followed by at least one of the other valid characters `([._][A-Za-z]+)?`

Put it all together and you have: `/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*([._][A-Za-z0-9]+)?$/`. Using the case '/i' insensitive flag lets you drop the 'A-Z': `/^[a-z][a-z0-9]*([._][a-z0-9]+)?$/i`.

Regular expressions are equivalent to [deterministic finite automatons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) (DFA). Studying them can help get a grasp on regular expressions. In particular, transitioning between states is directly applicable to your three points. The (reduced) state diagram for this language should be quite easy to understand:
[image: State diagram for /^[a-z][a-z0-9]*([._][a-z0-9])?/]

The DFA:

- starts in state 0
- transitions to state 1 if a letter is encountered,
- stays in state 1 as long as letters and digits are encountered,
- switches to state 2 if a period or underscore are encountered,
- switches to state 3 if a letters and digit is encountered,
- stays in state 3 as long as letters and digits are encountered,
- accepts the string if it ends in state 1 or 3

I call it "reduced" because there's a fifth, non-accepting state and edges leading to it that aren't shown. Basically, if a character is encountered other than one listed, the DFA transitions to the fifth, non-accepting state and stays there.

Comment: Your DFA doesn't have a failure point?

Comment: @abc123: states 2 and the hidden 4.

Comment: ... State 0 is also non-accepting, but Farhan has a separate check ensuring the string is at least 4 characters, so it wouldn't matter in practice.

Comment: I think I should use this..thanks a lot.

Comment: @FarhanIhsas: at this point, do you understand all the pieces? Could you write the regex yourself? You'll be doing yourself a disservice if you just use an answer without plumbing its depths.

Comment: your answer gave a better understanding..i think i can do, if do some practice..
+++++++++++  for you, and thanks to all.

One more help please, how to repute someone here?

Comment: @FarhanIhsas Make sure you accept the answer if it helped you and solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with the regular expression `^[a-z][a-z0-9]*([._][a-z0-9]+)?$`:

```
$regex = '/^[a-z][a-z0-9]*([._][a-z0-9]+)?$/i';
echo preg_match($regex, 'valid_user1'); # => 1
echo preg_match($regex, 'Valid_user1'); # => 1
echo preg_match($regex, '0invalid_user'); # => 0
echo preg_match($regex, 'invaliduser_'); # => 0
echo preg_match($regex, 'in_valid_user'); # => 0
```

**UPDATE**

Regular expression come from outis's answer.

Comment: your php is strong...your regex isn't as good as the below.

Comment: @abc123, Please let me know what I am missing. Thank you.

Comment: @falsetru: your pattern accept multiple underscores and dots.

Comment: [regex](http://regex101.com/r/oO2hA3) i recommend this and copy the regex explanation

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern allows usernames between 4 and 12 characters, with a letter as first character and only one dot and only one underscore:

```
$pattern = '~^(?=.{4,12}$)[a-z]++[^\W_]*+(_[^\W_]++)?+(?>\.[^\W_]++)?+(?(1)|(_[^\W_]++)?+)$~i';
```

You can use it with preg_match to check the username.

**pattern details**:

```
~                # pattern delimiter
^                # begining anchor
(?=.{4,12}$)     # lookahead assertion: check if the length is between 4 and 12
                 # characters. It stand for: "followed by between 4 and 12 chars
                 # and the end of the string
[a-z]++          # one or more letters
[^\W_]*+         # zero or more letters or digits. Since ^ means that the character
                 # class is negated, _ is excluded with all that is not a part of \w
(_[^\W_]++)?+    # first capturing group with an underscore and one or more
                 # letters/digits. The group is optional
(?>\.[^\W_]++)?+ # a non capturing group with a dot (optional too)
(?(1)            # conditional: if the first capturing group exist there is nothing
     |           # OR
   (_[^\W_]++)?+ # you can have an underscore here (optional)
)
$                # anchor: end of the string
~                # pattern delimiter
i                # case insensitive modifier
```

About "dumb username" you can not do much except writing a "blacklist" and check the username after (or in the pattern with a lookahead or a lookbehind) but I'm not sure that this will be very useful, since it is not a password.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a regular expression, but maybe I can persuade you that it can be done quite easily the old-fashioned way:

```
function validUsername($user) {

    // A few variables
    $minlen = 3;
    $maxlen = 20;
    $usrlen = strlen($user);

    // Allowed length of username
    if ($usrlen < $minlen || $usrlen > $maxlen) {
        return false;
    }
    // First character must be alpha
    if ( ! ctype_alpha($user[0])) {
        return false;
    }
    // Last letter cannot be . or _ which means
    // that it must be alphanum
    if ( ! ctype_alnum($user[$usrlen-1])) {
        return false;
    }
    // Go over each character, excluding the first
    // and last, because we have already dealt with them
    for ($i = 1; $i < $usrlen-1; $i++) {

        // Grab the currect character
        $char = $user[$i];

        // If it is alphanum then it is valid
        if (ctype_alnum($char)) {
            continue;
        }
        // Dots and underscores cannot appear in pairs
        elseif ($char === '.' || $char === '_') {
            if ($user[$i-1] === $char || $user[$i+1] === $char) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        // Character not supported
        else return false;
    }
    // Everything seems to be in order
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not so sure 19 non-trivial lines of code (blank lines, comments & block terminators are excluded) vs 1 line for the RE is what I would call "easily"; certainly not comparatively easily. Considering regexes date from the '50s and were used programmatically in the '60s, I'm also not so sure I'd call the non-regex approach the "old-fashioned" way.

Comment: regex is built for this

Comment: @outis 19 easily understood lines are better than cryptic one-line regexes in my experience, especially if you want novice programmers to contribute. By "old-fashioned" I just meant the straight-forward, no-nonsense way. Regular expression are incredibly nice in certain situations, but if you can avoid them then I think you will be better off in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I would still chose the faster method.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: sure, cryptic regexes are a barrier to understanding, but this situation doesn't call for a cryptic one. As for avoiding them, they can always be avoided, but sometimes the alternative basically has you create your own DFA and can be more complex than a regex. If it can be done in a *short* (fits in a terminal line, including code that invokes regex), *simple* regex, I'd always pick that. "Straight-forward" and "no-nonsense" still seem like weighted adjectives, more about personal preferences than any quality of the code.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen If you go to regex101.com you can learn RegEx so it isn't cryptic...it also will explain any pasted RegEx.  Regular Expressions are perfect for validation and I haven't meet a junior developer who could read all your code above and immediately understand it anymore than a regular expression...

Comment: @outis I don't get what is so complex about the code in my answer. If you want to go into automata theory, fine, but anyone with a basic understanding of programming can read it line by line and understand it without learning to read regular expressions. I suppose this has a lot to do with personal preference, but you make it sound like I am wrong in some way, which I do not think I am. I do not particularly disagree with anything you have said, though, for what it is worth.

Comment: @abc123 I can read regular expressions in my sleep. I just felt like this problem could easily be solved without regular expressions. I cannot count how often I have seen people using stuff like, `/\d+/`, without realizing that there are much simpler ways of doing stuff.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: your code isn't too complex, it's just more complex than the equivalent RE. I'm also not trying to imply that you're wrong, just that (as you say) the preference to stringently avoid regexes (or over-use them) is a personal one. Mostly, I prefer that personal preferences be made explicit, rather than stating them in more absolute terms. Plus, I don't want to scare the children away from REs. (As for `/\d+/` (rather, `/^\d+$/` or `/\D/`), I like `ctype_digit()` myself, though I don't consider it simpler than the REs.)

Comment: I didn't mean to make this personal against you.  When I stated you could learn reflex at regex101 I should of explained I was meaning the general you anyone reading the post your answer is coded properly and well commented in this situation I would recommend regex purely for its speed and ease of use.  This perhaps is personal preference on my part however the speed on this particular problem is faster with a RegEx.  Sorry if I offended you in any way that was not my intent.

Comment: @abc123 I did not take it personally. And I did not mean to offend. Okay, this is becoming a chat. Over and out.